# Rails query: Find first record value and display in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm currently trying to display the first record. The record is updated when someone decides to buy a wine. How would I get the first record for the specific wine ?

I thought of using .find(1)? but how would implement this into my controller ?

My current controller:

```
  def create
    wine = Wine.find(params[:wine_id])

    if current_user == wine.user
      flash[:alert] = "Du kannst nicht deinen eigenen Wein kaufen!"
    else

    start_date = Date.parse(reservation_params[:start_date])

    @reservation = current_user.reservations.build(reservation_params)
    @reservation.wine = wine
    @reservation.price = wine.price
    @reservation.in_stock = wine.in_stock - @reservation.bottle
    @reservation.total = wine.price * @reservation.bottle
    wine.update(in_stock: @reservation.in_stock)
    # @reservation.save

  if @reservation.save
    if wine.Reservieren?
      flash[:notice] = "Reserviert!"
  else
    @reservation.Versendet!
    flash[:notice] = "Eroflgreich bestellt!"
  end
else
    flash[:alert] = "Can't make a reservation!"
  end

  end
    redirect_to wine
  end
```

My current view:

```
<% @wines.each do |wine| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= link_to wine.wine_name, wine_path(wine) %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= wine.in_stock %> <!-- Display first record -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <% if !wine.in_stock.blank? %>
        Aktiv
        <% else %>
        Nicht Aktiv
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 right">
        <%= link_to "Update", details_wine_path(wine), class: "btn btn-form" %>
      </div>
    </div><!-- row -->
    <hr/>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can explain a little better your code, because you receive `@wines` in your view and it is not coming from this controller action that you posted.

But if you want to take the first register you can basically call `wines.first`.
You would change from  `<%= wine.in_stock %>` to  `<%= @wines.first %>` for example.

Here is some thread related:
[Display first record in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347741/display-first-record-in-rails?rq=1)